# Did vikings really travel as far as the Middle-east?

Tags: middle-east, vikings

I've heard some rumors that Vikings have travelled as far as the Middle-east, and that would be where they've gotten the secret of making their steel so efficient, so early in history.

Is that a thing? Did they actually :

- Travel all the way to the middle east?
- Traded, with the locals?

And if they did, do we have any documentation, written journals perhaps, of how they reacted to such different climates?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: [Björn Ironside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bj%C3%B6rn_Ironside) raided Luna in Italy (mistaking it for Rome), and Moscow was founded by Swedish Vikings. The [Kingdom of Sicily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_conquest_of_southern_Italy) was founded by Norman relatives of William the Conqueror  about the same time as his conquest of England.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_expansion#Islamic_Levant http://sciencenordic.com/old-arabic-texts-describe-dirty-vikings

Comment: Also, the related article [Caspian expeditions of the Rus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspian_expeditions_of_the_Rus') may be of interest.

Comment: And also the Byzantine Empire's Varangian Guard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varangian_Guard  (Note that I'm using Viking in the same sense you seem to be, as a generic term for Norse people.  Viking was actually more of a job description, for those who went out raiding.)

Comment: Viking swords made out of Damascus steel, the Ulfbehrt swords, have been found, indicating that if they didn't actually get to the ME, at the least, they were carrying on  commerce with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer revised to a Yes: jamesqf correctly pointed out the example of the [Varangian Guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varangian_Guard) in Constantinople.

Back in Scandinavia, Viking burial materials were [found to carry Arabic and Muslim motifs](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-41567391). Metcalf's paper *What happened to Islamic dirhams after their arrival in the Northern Lands?* discusses hoards of coinage acquired directly from the mints far to the south.

There are also more dubious claims about such contact. J. Edgar Taylor's *Vikings in the Gulf: fact or fancy?* dismisses a specific claim that "Medieval Vikings hauled two or more ships across the Isthmus of Suez and sailed through the Red Sea to the Persian Gulf".

Comment: There is plenty of evidence, assuming that by "Viking" you mean Norse people in general.  (Because, as I note above, "viking" is really more of a job description.)  Much of the interchange was through modern day Russia & Ukraine, along the Volga and into the Black Sea, not via Gibraltar & the Mediterranean.

Comment: @jamesqf evidence of Viking/Nordic people _reaching the Middle East_? Please muster it.

Comment: The Byzantine Empire's Varangian Guard: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varangian_Guard  The institution existed for centuries, recruiting members from northern Europe, principally the Norse countries.

Comment: There are also runestone attestations of persons going to Jerusalem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broby_bro_Runestones

Comment: @jamesqf Quite right. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: The Norman [Kingdom of Sicily under Robert II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_II_of_Sicily#Later_reign) also conquered parts of Tunisia, usually regarded as part of the Middle East, plus Tripoli and Cape Bona. Roger also made war against Byzantium during the Second Crusade. Richard's grandson [William I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_II_of_Sicily#Wars_with_Egypt_and_Byzantine_Empire) attacked cities in Egypt in support of the Third Crusade.